# How to map a 2D-Array to a collection of "array-objects" with automapper?

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-core, mapping, automapper

I have a class that contains a 2D-Array and a class with a collection of ArrayValue objects (shown below). How can i map between those 2 classes?

```cs
class ArrayMap {
    int[,] map;
}
```

```cs
class CollectionMap {
    ICollection<ArrayValue> map;
}
```

```cs
class ArrayValue {
    int x;
    int y;
    int value;
}
```

Is it able to map these classes with Automapper or do I have to code my own mapping?

Comment: While AutoMapper can map a 2d array to another 2d array, I doubt it has anything built in for 2d array to 1d array. You'll probably need your own conversion code to supply to the map in AutoMapper .

Comment: Share us the data for `ArrayMap` and the expected value for `CollectionMap`.

Comment: you are asking __How can I map between those 2 classes__ and sharing the code of __3 classes__ which is confusing, please edit the question and add more clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this kind of custom mapping by implementing [value converter](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Value-converters.html):

```cs
public class CollectionMapConverter : IValueConverter<int[,], ICollection<ArrayValue>>
{
    public ICollection<ArrayValue> Convert(int[,] sourceMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var collection = new List<ArrayValue>();

        for (var x = 0; x < sourceMember.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (var y = 0; y < sourceMember.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                collection.Add(new ArrayValue
                {
                    value = sourceMember[x, y],
                    x = x,
                    y = y,
                });
            }
        }

        return collection;
    }
}
```

then specify its usage when configurating map between `ArrayMap` and `CollectionMap`:

```cs
configuration.CreateMap<ArrayMap, CollectionMap>()
    .ForMember(collectionMap => collectionMap.map, options =>
    {
        options.ConvertUsing(new CollectionMapConverter());
    });
```

I assumed first dimension applies to a horizontal axis (X) and second one - to the vertical axis (Y). The current manner of reading the two-dimensional array is starting from the top left corner [0; 0] and going down (Y++), till the end of rows (Y), then stepping one column further (X++) and starting again the from the top (Y = 0). Repeat until the end of columns.

Eventually, mapping a two-dimensional `int` array shown below:

```
+------------------->
|                   X
|   +---+---+
|   | 1 | 4 |
|   +---+---+
|   | 2 | 5 |
|   +---+---+
|   | 3 | 6 |
|   +---+---+
|
|
v Y
```

will result in a collection of 6 `ArrayValue` elements:

[image]

If you would like to have other order, then you would have construct the `for` loops differently.